# Get week start date (Monday) from a date column in Python (pandas)?

Tags: python, date, numpy, pandas

I have seen a lot of posts about how you can do it with a date string but I am trying something for a dataframe column and haven't got any luck so far.
My current method is : Get the weekday from 'myday' and then offset to get monday.

```
df['myday'] is column of dates. 
mydays = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['myday']).weekday
df['week_start'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['myday']) - pd.DateOffset(days=mydays)
```

But I get 
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: numpy.ndarray

How can I get week start date from a df column?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it fails because pd.DateOffset expects a single integer as a parameter (and you are feeding it an array). You can only use DateOffset to change a date column by the same offset.

try this :

```
import datetime as dt
# Change 'myday' to contains dates as datetime objects
df['myday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['myday'])  
# 'daysoffset' will container the weekday, as integers
df['daysoffset'] = df['myday'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday())
# We apply, row by row (axis=1) a timedelta operation
df['week_start'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['myday'] - dt.TimeDelta(days=x['daysoffset']), axis=1)
```

I haven't actually tested this code, (there was no sample data), but that should work for what you have described.

However, you might want to look at [pandas.Resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), which might provide a better solution - depending on exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation. This solution does exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Should the `TimeDelta` not refer to `df['daysoffset']`?

Comment: using lambda will result in something slow

Answer (score 58):

Another alternative:

```
df['week_start'] = df['myday'].dt.to_period('W').apply(lambda r: r.start_time)
```

This will set 'week_start' to be the first Monday before the time in 'myday'.

You can choose different week starts via [anchored offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets) e.g. `’W-THU’` to start the week on Thursday instead. (Thanks @Henry Ecker for that suggestion)

Comment: Thanks for this. `df['myday'].dt.to_period('W').dt.start_time` is probably faster than using `apply` (not sure when is this introduced, might not work for older pandas version)

Comment: It is possible to set an arbitrary day to start the week with [anchored offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets). Sunday start would be `'W-SUN'` or Thursday Start `'W-THU'`.

Comment: @HenryEcker Thanks!! This should be added into this answer to cover more broader aspect

Comment: For reference, where I can see documentation how to know the possible .dt options have? chaining .dt was not expected but awesome

Answer (score 42):

While both [@knightofni's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28007636/3622349) and [@Paul's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35613515/3622349) solutions work I tend to try to stay away from using apply in Pandas because it is usually quite slow compared to array-based methods.  In order to avoid this, after casting to a datetime column (via `pd.to_datetime`) we can modify the weekday based method and simply cast the day of the week to be a [numpy timedelta64[D]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic) by either casting it directly:

```
df['week_start'] = df['myday'] - df['myday'].dt.weekday.astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

or by using [to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) as [@ribitskiyb suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49255286/3622349):

```
df['week_start'] = df['myday'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['myday'].dt.weekday, unit='D').
```

Using test data with 60,000 datetimes I got the following times using the suggested answers using the newly released Pandas 1.0.1.

```
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x['myday'] - datetime.timedelta(days=x['myday'].weekday()), axis=1)
>>> 1.33 s ± 28.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df['myday'].dt.to_period('W').apply(lambda r: r.start_time)
>>> 5.59 ms ± 138 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df['myday'] - df['myday'].dt.weekday.astype('timedelta64[D]')
>>> 3.44 ms ± 106 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df['myday'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['myday'].dt.weekday, unit='D')
>>> 3.47 ms ± 170 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

These results show that Pandas 1.0.1 has dramatically improved the speed of the to_period apply based method (vs Pandas <= 0.25) but show that converting directly to a timedelta (by either casting the type directly `.astype('timedelta64[D]')` or using `pd.to_timedelta` is still superior. Based on these results I would suggest using `pd.to_timedelta` going forward.

Comment: How does this work?  df['myday'].dt.weekday.astype('timedelta64[D]') in my dataset returns a series of all zeroes.  Why or how would subtracted 0 from df['myday']  work?  This seems like the best solution.

Comment: Clarifying the above post, the way I understand what is going on is that basically it is saying take the date and then subtract the dayofweek from it.  But what I don't understand is why .astype('timedelta64[D]') results in all zeros.

Comment: @DonQuixote Probably your 'myday' frequency is less than '1D'. This won't work then. You have to modify it to subtract hours, minutes, etc.

Answer (score 13):

(Just adding to [n8yoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39839592/2243714)'s answer)

Using `.astype('timedelta64[D]')` seems not so readable to me -- found an alternative using just the functionality of pandas:

```
df['myday'] - pd.to_timedelta(arg=df['myday'].dt.weekday, unit='D')
```

Comment: I liked the lambda expression from @Paul, but this answer is much, much faster and equally "pithy".  Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Convert column to pandas datetime equivalent
df['myday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['myday']) 

# Create function to calculate Start Week date
week_start_date = lambda date: date - timedelta(days=date.weekday())

# Apply above function on DataFrame column
df['week_start_date'] = df['myday'].apply(week_start_date)
```