# How do get start_of_week(Monday) from dates in other column in dataframe

Tags: pandas, time, time-series

I need to get for each value, beginning of week (Monday).
Here is dataframe that I have

[image]

And I want to get beginning of week `purchase_date_x` column to create new column with new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
df['Monday_date_x'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('W').dt.start_time
```

You can find more information on it here:
[Get week start date (Monday) from a date column in Python (pandas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989120/get-week-start-date-monday-from-a-date-column-in-python-pandas)

Comment: No need for apply here, better use `dt.start_time` that is vectorized

Comment: Is that for performance?